# Regressorgrams in R similarity using tapply

Tags: r

I've got this R-code that is used to set up several regressorgrams, using the idea of binwidth, where 20.625, 27.5,41.25,82.5 are binwidths, got these thanks to a friend.

```
Data=read.table(paste0("http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry",
                       "/all-of-nonpar/=data/lidar.dat"),
                header=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
x=Data$range
y=Data$logratio

#Parameter setup
rvalues<-max(x)-min(x)

doplot=function(h){
bin<-ceiling(rvalues/h)
W<-matrix(nrow=length(x),ncol=bin)
for (j in 1:bin){
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i]>=(min(x)+(j-1)*h) && x[i]<(min(x)+(j)*h)){W[i,j]=1}
    else {W[i,j]=0}}}
W[length(x),bin]=1
fit=rep(0,bin)
for (j in 1:bin){
  fit[j]=sum(y*W[,j]/sum(W[,j]))}
fit[bin+1]=fit[bin]
t<-numeric(bin)
length(fit)
for (j in 1:(bin+1)){
  t[j]=(min(x))+(j-1)*h}
plot(x,y, ylab="log ratio", xlab="range")
lines(t,fit,type="s",col=1,lwd=2)}

for (h in c(82.5,41.25,27.5,20.625)){
  doplot(h)}
```

The above code generates the following result,

[image]

Which is the proper image with the proper bins, however, I was using some old code that I had from a week ago which was,

```
Data=read.table(paste0("http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry",
                       "/all-of-nonpar/=data/lidar.dat"),
                header=TRUE)
x=Data$range
y=Data$logratio
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
doplot=function(h){
  breaks=hist(x, breaks=h, plot=FALSE)$breaks
  fit=tapply(y, cut(x, breaks), mean)
  plot(x, y,  xlab="range", ylab="log ratio")
  lines(breaks, c(fit[2], fit) , type="S", col = 1, lwd = 2)
  title(paste("Number of bins are", h))
}
for(h in c(20.625,27.5,41.25,82.5)){
  doplot(h)
}
```

Which produces similar plots however they are a lot more sporadic.
[image]
AM I using the tapply function completely wrong here or is there a small error that I am not getting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, for some reason none of the images are showing up.

Comment: In the first case you are using the binwidths properly. In the second case you are passing the vector as a _number_ of bins to hist.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand the difference. I'll have to do a bit more research to see if any functions can handle this. If not it's not a worry. Thanks.